# PHP logged in system - Proper way to implement HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm currently adding a log-in system to the website i'm working on, and i came to the point where i have to add a session_start() to every page so that unlogged users can not access them.

Here is what it looks like for the "main.php" :

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) || $_SESSION['status']=='false'){
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body style="background:url("img/404.png")"?></body></html>';
}
else{
// Very Long HTML ONLY code displaying the actual page 
} ?>
```

The login form is located in the "index.php" and handled with javascript. 
NB: $users is an array populated by an AJAX call to the database, and contains all data correlated to every user.

```
$('#logForm').submit(function(){
    var $user=document.forms["logForm"]["user"].value;
    var $pass=document.forms["logForm"]["pass"].value;

    for(var i=0;i<$users.length;i++){
        if($users[i]['user'].trim() == $user.trim() && $users[i]['password'] == $pass.trim()){
            if($users[i]['status']==1){
                $_SESSION['status']=true;
                $_SESSION['user']=$user[i]['user'];
                return true;
            }
            else{
                alert("Your registration is being processed")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Wrong Logs");
    return false;
});
```

My question is really simple : 
For the "main.php" i don't want to copy all the HTML code into the php else bracket since it makes it really unpractical to update or even see what's going on for future changes or updates on the code (everything appears in the same color inside the echo for the text editor, i'm using Sublime text). 
So i was wondering isn't there any more elegant and professional way to handle this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include a different file:

```
else{
// Very Long HTML ONLY code displaying the actual page 
    include('index.php');
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, you can add HTML to your PHP script.

To solve your issue in the `else` clause - for a more dynamic and easily updatable content - you can create a separate file and `include` where it would be appropriate:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) || $_SESSION['status']=='false'){
    echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><body style="background:url("img/404.png")"?></body></html>';
}
else {
    include 'somepage.html';
}
?>
```

Or if you have an `autoloader` or `preload` file you can add some rule which decides what content comes up.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is trying to keep business logic out of your display files and then using PHP's alternative syntax, or some type of template engine, for your templates:

In your business logic, you may have:

```
<?php
$status = true;
if(!isset($_SESSION['status']) || $_SESSION['status']=='false'){
   $status = false;
}
include "template.php";
?>
```

In your template, you may have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php if($status): ?>
    <body>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
<?php else: ?>
    <body style="background:url("img/404.png")"></body>
<?php endif; ?>
</html>
```

This approach, being separation of concerns, is used by MVC frameworks.  This is a very basic example of a controller and view, but I suggest you read up on MVC designs if you are enticed.